# Django: import error that refer to template tags

Tags: django, import, django-templates

I'm having a headache with some errors that appear suddenly on an application I'm developing. One time I solved it using complete imports (including the project dir) but this time the error has no sense.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Could not import e_cidadania.apps.proposals.views. Error was: cannot import name User
```

And marked code is:

```
<a href="{% url password_reset %}">{% trans "Lost your password?" %}</a>
```

The import line at views.py:24

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I must say, 24h before everything was working fine and no changes were made to the repo.

I've looked the url and the view, both are fine. I've run `manage.py shell` and tested the import, works fine. I did put some markers in the code to test how it was running and the program crashes exactly importing the `User` model in that file (there are lots of imports User in the application and not one of them gave a warning). Even deleting the import from thefile gives the same error!

How can I track this to know what is the real problem?

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that the marked error is in the `userprofile` module, and the proper error is given in the `proposals` module, a module that has **absolutely nothing** to do with userprofile.

**UPDATE 2**: You can see the code [here](http://gitorious.org/e-cidadania/mainline), the application is GPL so there is no problem.

Comment: are you importing e_cidadania.apps.proposals.views in any urls module ? if yes, does the error still occours if you remove from there ?

Comment: Yes, in the proposals url.py file. I haven't tried and I can't try it until night (at spain)

Comment: How can deleting that line still give that same error?? That makes it sound like django is using a different version of the file than you think. Are you maybe editing a different branch of your code than django is running?

Comment: I am currently having the exact same problem, but can't figure out why it is happening to me either. My case is a little different though. Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "relation" between userprofile and proposals modules is that you probably refer to both in the urls definition, which is used to do the reverse when using {% url 'whatever.viewname' [args] %} there probably you do import some view function from both.

I would start having a look at modules you're importing there.

I had this annoying problem (more than once) and most of the time it was caused by recursive imports or by a order dependent imports that I was not aware of (because most of the times "was working").

Comment: I have reviewed the code. There are no clashes on imports or views. The "userprofile" module is completely separated from the rest of the application (is the django-userprofile module, without modifications)